# How to perform binning in order to discretize continuous features for feature selection in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection, continuous-data, binning

If I wanted to use uncertainty measures e.g. information gain for feature selection continuous features need to be discretized. How can I do this in R?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you come to the idea that using information gain (or other uncertainty measure) _requires_ discretization of continuous features? In general it does not

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I have read it in a paper: Supervised feature selection: A tutorial from Samuel H. Huang. In general do I need some preprocessing steps for feature selection?

Comment: The idea of discarding much of the information in your data just so you can use a certain algorithm is very troubling.

Comment: Thats true! Havent thought about that. I am new to feature selection so I am still learning and do lots of trial and error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about using information gain (IG) formula, it can indeed only be calculated for discretized features and target.

If you are talking about using feature selection algorithm that is based on IG and that is already implemented (as opposed to developing your own algorithm from scratch),  discretization of features typically (or always?) is a part of the algorithm. Such algorithms are directly applicable to the classification tasks (that is, your target need to be discrete).

In R have a look, for example, at the `FSelector` package, in particular, at the `information.gain(formula, data)` function. Follow the example from the reference manual (see "entropy.based" there).